# is it possible to take a large number of files & tar/gzip and stream them on-the-fly?

Tags: backup, tar, on-the-fly

I have a large number of files which I need to backup, problem is there isn't enough disk space to create a tar file of them and then upload it offsite. Is there a way of using python, php or perl to tar up a set of files and upload them on-the-fly without making a tar file on disk? They are also way too large to store in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always do this just via ssh:

```
tar czf - FILES/* | ssh me@someplace "tar xzf -"
```

This way, the files end up all unpacked on the other machine. Alternatively

```
tar czf - FILES/* | ssh me@someplace "cat > foo.tgz"
```

Puts them in an archive on the other machine, which is what you actually wanted.

Comment: does that create the entire tar file in memory first? I'm wondering if its memory intensive.

Comment: No, it doesn't -- the data gets sent over the network right away; only a few file blocks are held in memory at a time. You can can transfer entire filesystems this way!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would require some programming. Any FTP library is going to let you send a stream to a remote file; you'd have to code  up the archive-building, and have it stream the archive as it's built. Same principle, but I can't think of any way to put it together without coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of tar over ssh:

```
tar zcvf - testdir/ | ssh user@domain.com "cat > testdir.tar.gz"
```